# Group by multiple columns and split by month/year grouping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need help with doing pivot table on Pandas.

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| Date             | Product | Status of Order | # of Orders | Total Order Value |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| January 1, 2016  | Windows | Cancelled       | 360         | 1000              |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| January 2, 2016  | Mac     | Cancelled       | 120         | 2000              |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| January 3, 2016  | Mac     | Completed       | 940         | 500               |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| ...              | ...     | ...             | ...         | ...               |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| February 1, 2016 | Windows | Completed       | 60          | 1300              |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| February 1, 2016 | Mac     | Cancelled       | 420         | 2500              |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| February 3, 1916 | Windows | Completed       | 610         | 3400              |
+------------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

And I would like to pivot it this way:

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| Product | Status of Order | Sum of #ofOrders in January | Sum of #ofOrders in February |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| Windows | Completed       | 0                           | 670                          |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|         | Cancelled       | 360                         | 0                            |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| Mac     | Completed       | 940                         | 0                            |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|         | Cancelled       | 120                         | 420                          |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
```

What I've tried was df.set_index('Date').resample('M')["# of Orders"].sum(), but what I really want is to group by 'Product', 'Status of Order', and 'Sum of #ofOrders', and perform then perform sum... This usually takes a few clicks and a minute on Excel pivot table, but I've been banging my head for the past hour with Pandas...

Below is the codes to create the table (random values).

```
import pandas as pd
# create data frame
df_time = pd.DataFrame( {'Date': pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=50, freq='H') })
df_time = pd.concat([df_time]*2, ignore_index=True)

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Product':['Windows', 'Mac', 'Mac', 'Windows', 'Mac'],
         'Status of Order':['Cancelled', 'Cancelled', 'Completed', 'Cancelled', 'Completed'],
         '# of Orders':[100,200,140,430,210],
         'Total Order Value':[1000,2000,1500,5400,2500]})
df_raw = pd.concat([df_raw]*20, ignore_index=True)

df = pd.concat([df_time, df_raw], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps

Groupby month and sum all orders

`temp_df =  df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'Product', 'Status of Order']).agg({'# of Orders': 'sum'}).reset_index()`

Then pivot the `date and orders` and merge back with the `temp_df`

`df = temp_df[['Product', 'Status of Order']].merge(temp_df[['Date', '# of Orders']].pivot(columns='Date', values='# of Orders').fillna(0), left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Finally you can sort it

`df = df.sort_values(['Product'])`

Result

```
   Product Status of Order  2016-01-31 00:00:00  2016-02-29 00:00:00
0      Mac       Cancelled               2400.0                  0.0
1      Mac       Completed               4410.0                  0.0
3      Mac       Cancelled                  0.0               1600.0
4      Mac       Completed                  0.0               2590.0
2  Windows       Cancelled               6460.0                  0.0
5  Windows       Cancelled                  0.0               4140.0
```

Comment: Hi, this returned an error, and so I added key='Date' in here: temp_df =  df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'), 'Product', 'Status of Order']).agg({'# of Orders': 'sum'}).reset_index(), and this fixes it. For the second query, I used pivot_table like this and it was much easier: temp_df1 = pd.pivot_table(temp_df, index = ['Product', 'Status of Order'], columns='Date'). Thanks much, wouldn't have figured it out otherwise...

Comment: please accept if this is the answer you were looking for, it really helps :)